# Inline dropdown-menu <li> when using bootstrap glyphicons that right align

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, smarty

I have added right aligned (`pull-right`) bootstrap `glyphicons` to my `dropdown-menu` options. The problem is that the longest option gets a line break between the name and the `glyphicon`. How can I make them on them same line? When I try without `pull-right` everything aligns perfect.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a
            href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"
            aria-haspopup="true"
            aria-expanded="false">
                menu
                <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            {foreach from=$item key=sub_title item=sub_item}
                    <li>
                        <a
                            href="{$sub_item.url}"
                            target="_blank">
                            {$sub_title}
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{$sub_item.icon} pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            {/foreach}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is how it looks [link](http://imgur.com/DKbV4aL)
On the last option the line is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let's wrap the text in a separate block.
2. The icon with `float: right;` has to go before the text.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.item-text {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">short short</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">long long long long long long long long long long long long long</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">short short</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">short short</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">long long long long long long long long long long long long long</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#URL" target="_blank">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="item-text">long long long long long long long long long long long long long</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger visible-xs text-center">
  Menu becomes visible in the window with a width of 768px or more.
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```